# When downloading a file using ResponseEntity in Spring, byte breaks in reaction

Tags: reactjs, spring, file, download

This is a method of downloading files from Spring to ResponseEntity.

When you download it, the byte breaks and comes out.

If you use tag a, you can download the file without breaking it, but it is difficult to put the event after downloading the file using response.

Is there a way?

// Spring

```
Resource resource = qnaService.loadAsResource(tempFileName);
        File file = resource.getFile();

    if (file.exists()) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
        headers.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", fileName);
        headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        headers.set("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");


        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=" + OriginFileName)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .contentLength(file.length())
                .body(new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file)));
    }
```

// React

```
 const data = await request({
                url: `/api/qna/file/test/${node.qnaFileID}`,
                method: request.method.get(),
            });
            console.log(data);
            const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/xml;charset=utf-8' });
            saveAs(blob, node.name);
```

// Data is broken.

data: "�PNG\r\n\u001a\n\u0000\u0000\u0000\rIHDR\u0000\u0000\t�\u0000\u0000\u0004z\b\u0006\u0000\u0000\u0000�س]\u0000\u0000\fliCCPICC Profile\u0000\u0000H��W\u0007XS�\u0016�[RIh\u0001\u0004���\u0004�\u001a@J\b-��"�\bI �Ę\u0010T�eQ���\b��U\u0011Ŷ\u0002bǮ,��/\u0016T�uQ\u0017\u0

Answer (score 0):

just add responseType: blob to your request

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).